# Can you compare AIC to WAIC?

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, aic, poisson-regression, waic

This may be a simple question, but I'm at a bit of a loss.

Can I compare AIC to WAIC for the same model, one estimated using general linear models and one using Bayesian estimation?

Or do I need to compare models using the same information criterion?

Motivation for the question:

The glm models are preliminary and ultimately inform the choice of more complex Bayesian models. Given the number of models I am running, I am trying to save some time by using glm where possible.

Comment: I think the answer is negative, but you could fit the frequentist model with a flat prior and compare both models Bayesianly, possibly using WAIC, but definitely not by using a Bayes Factor.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes there doesn't seem to be a lot of active comparison of AIC to WAIC, so I guess I will just need to quickly re-run all the GLM models using a Bayesian estimator. Not too much of a headache I guess. 

If you have any official sources or explanation as to why they cannot be compared, would be greatly appreciated.